# Bind window scroll the AngularJS way

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS newbie here with a jQuery background. Using AngularJS, I'm attempting to develop a fixed-top navbar with a background that transitions from transparent to opaque on window scroll. However, I'm having trouble binding the window scroll to the $scope.

Here's what I have so far that doesn't work:

http://jsfiddle.net/brettwick86/pt33te3z/3/

```
function bgScroll($scope) {
  angular.element(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    $scope.scroll = window.pageYOffset;
    $scope.height = document.getElementById('main-header').offsetHeight;
    $scope.a = $scope.scroll / $scope.height;
    $scope.bgColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,' + $scope.a + ')';
  });
}
```

View:

```
<div ng-controller="bgScroll">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-bw navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="background-color: {{ bgColor }};">
    ...
  </nav>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`angular.element` delegates to jQuery (when it's included) or JQlite, which means that callback functions don't automatically apply changes to your `$scope`.

```
function bgScroll($scope) {
  angular.element(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    $scope.scroll = window.pageYOffset;
    $scope.height = document.getElementById('main-header').offsetHeight;
    $scope.a = $scope.scroll / $scope.height;
    $scope.bgColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,' + $scope.a + ')';

    // Apply the changes to the scope here
    $scope.$apply();
  });
}
```

Comment: Note: `angular.element` delegates to **`JQuery`** only when it is included, otherwise it uses angular's **`JQlite`** which is a lite version of JQuery.

Comment: @ryeballar reflected in answer

Comment: Thanks for the help.`$scope.$apply();` is exactly what I was missing. I know about jQlite, but did not understand how the $scope object relates to angular.element, so the callback explanation is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid doing dom manipulation in the controller. Instead create a new directive and do it there.

```
enter code here


<div bg-scroll ng-controller="bgScroll">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-bw navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="background-color: {{ bgColor }};">
    ...
  </nav>
</div>   
myapp.directive('bgScroll', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            angular.element(window).bind('scroll', function () {
               scope.scroll = window.pageYOffset;
               scope.height = document.getElementById('main-header').offsetHeight;
               scope.a = scope.scroll / scope.height;
               scope.bgColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,' + scope.a + ')';
            });
scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        angular.element(window).unbind('scroll');
      });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: In my code, I thought the DOM manipulation occurred in the view: `<nav ... style="background-color: {{ bgColor }};">` Is this not correct?